# Fundamental matrix of $y''+\epsilon f(t)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

I converted this ode into a linear matrix form like $y'=Ay$ and tried to solve this, but I couldn't find a fundamental solution which satisfies $\Phi (0)=I$, which is required in one of my assignment questions. Is it possible? Because I think there is no such fundamental matrix.

Btw, $f(t)=1$ if $0<=t<\pi$, 0 if $\pi <=t<2\pi$, and it is $2\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Solve the problem on $[0, \pi), [\pi,2 \pi)$ separately. Why do you think a solution is not possible?

Comment: do you already try: $y'=z$? then you would have a system of two equations  together with $z'=-\varepsilon f y$

Comment: copper.hat i mean the fundamental solution evaluated at 0 is not I. janmarqz i used that method to convert the ode.

Comment: @Checkman: It must be. The state at time zero is the state at time zero, so the fundamental **must** be $I$.

Comment: Ah i found what i was wrong. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the character of the solution depends on the sign of $\epsilon$.

Let $A_t = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -t \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. You need only evaluate $\Phi(t,0)$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi)$.

Then if the initial condition is $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, the solution
for $t \in [0,\pi)$ is given by $e^{A_\epsilon t} y_0$, and the value for
$t \in [\pi,2 \pi)$ will be $e^{A_0 (t-\pi)} e^{A_\epsilon \pi} y_0$, etc, etc.

Hence $\Phi(t,0) = \begin{cases} e^{A_\epsilon t}, & t \in [0,\pi) \\
e^{A_0 (t-\pi)} e^{A_\epsilon \pi}, & t \in [\pi, 2 \pi) \end{cases}$.

It is easy to see that $\Phi(0,0) = I$.

If $t = 2 \pi n + \theta$, with $\theta \in [0,2 \pi)$, then we see
$\Phi(t,0) = \Phi(\theta, 0) \Phi(0, 2 \pi)^n$.

Finally, since $\Phi(t,0) = \Phi(t, t_0) \Phi(t_0, 0)$, we have
$\Phi(t, t_0) = \Phi(t,0) \Phi(t_0, 0)^{-1}$.